# How can I construct this max aggregate sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with student name, test score, and city of residence. I would like to select the highest test score broken down by unique city and include the name of the student who received that score.

Can someone help construct this sql query?

Comment: Which version of Oracle do you use ?

Comment: Do you need only one row which is the highest score per city ? am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

You are a bit light on details here, but something like this *might* do it

```
select *
from (
  select 
    s.*,
    row_number() over ( partition by student_name, city order by test_score desc ) as seq
  from student s
)
where seq = 1
```

Comment: I edited the question for more clarity. Is there no way to do this without partition?

Answer (score 1):

Title says that you should use `MAX`.

This will return maximum score per city:

```
select s.city, 
       max(s.score) max_score
from student s
group by s.city
```

Use it as an inline view:

```
select a.student_name, 
       m.city,
       m.max_score
from student a join (select s.city,
                            max(s.score) max_score
                     from student s
                     group by s.city
                    ) m
                on a.city = m.city
               and a.score = m.max_score
order by m.city
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can do this using aggregation functions:

```
select city, max(score),
       max(name) keep (dense_rank first order by score desc)
from t
group by city;
```

The `keep` syntax is Oracle's rather verbose way of implementing a "first()" aggregation function.